# How to specify ASP.NET Core target framework imports in .csproj file (instead of project.json)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core

I'm building an ASP.NET Core app, and am trying to install the Azure Storage package.

From the Azure Storage github page, it says I need to place the following in my project.json file - but since this is using the latest ASP.NET Core version, we don't have a project.json file, just a .csproj file.

```
"imports": [
    "dnxcore50",
    "portable-net451+win8"
  ]
```

Is there a way to do this in .csproj file? I assume the place might be somewhere around this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: project.json/.csproj isn't ASP.NET Core related, it depends on the version of VS Tools installed and the new csproj structure is only available for VS 2017 (preview4 of the tools). VS2015 still uses preview2/2-1

Comment: Right - I'm using Visual Studio on Mac with the ASP.NET Core template it provides.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After migrating one of my projects to the new model, this is what it generated:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.6</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>TestApp</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageTargetFallback Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.6' ">$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Try adding dnxcore50 and portable-net451+win8 in a similar fashion, something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <PackageTargetFallback Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.1' ">$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50;portable-net451+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Does this add dependency on .NET 451, and if it does, will it no longer be able able to run on Linux? Thanks.

Comment: I was doing this on a Mac, so I assume fine on Linux as well.

Comment: My project was somehow switched from `netcoreapp1.1` to `net452` which cause Bad Image runtime errors on startup. Reverting the change fixed this.