# Using WindowsAzure.Storage in ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage

I'm using VS 2017 RC.  I've been told to use it to get the proper experience with .net core going forward, so that is where I am at.

I am trying to add the nuget package `WindowsAzure.Storage` into my ASP.NET Core application.  I keep getting a message stating that one of the dependencies is not compatible.

From reading up in some various forums, the problem appears to be the OData dependency.  Additional reading has shown that if this were running under VS 2015, I could use an `imports` statement in the `project.json` file to get this to work.

**Question:** what is the equivalent statement that I can add an `imports` statement into the vs2017rc proj file?

Comment: You can find the answer in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40709129/1658906

Comment: Thanks Juunas, that seems to have solved it.  Unfortunately, my internet has gone out here so I can't properly thank you.  I'm just hoping that this message eventually gets to you.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

> what is the equivalent statement that I can add an imports statement into the vs2017rc proj file?

PackageTargetFallback is a new design for Imports and is used in csproj, if you’d like to know detailed information, please read [this documentation](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/PackageTargetFallback-(new-design-for-Imports)).