# How to add support for "portable-net45+win8"?

Tags: azure, .net-core

I'm following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-receive-eph.

The article tells you to add the following to the project.json file:

Add the string "portable-net45+win8" to the "imports" declaration, within the "frameworks" section like this:

```
 "frameworks": {
   "netcoreapp1.0": {
     "imports": [
       "dnxcore50",
       "portable-net45+win8"
     ]
   }
 }
```

The problem is that with the new versions of the tooling (I'm using VS 2017), there is no project.json file in the .NET Core solution.

How is this done now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify ASP.NET Core target framework imports in .csproj file (instead of project.json)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697420/how-to-specify-asp-net-core-target-framework-imports-in-csproj-file-instead-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you migrate to `.csproj` you'll find the following:

```
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;dnxcore50;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
```

Perform the migration from `project.json` with `dotnet migrate` and it'll be done for you.